The text is rendered to stripes in QML
I'm using QML to build an application, but I encountered a strange rendering error. It looks like this:

As you can see, the text is rendered as stripes.
What I did was use Text normally, and when I restarted the application, it returned to normal. This issue only happened once and has never been reproduced again. My Qt version is 5.15.15, and my operating system is macOS.
What could be the possible reasons for this situation? Furthermore, how can I solve it?
I have no ideas; the only thing I can do is restart the application.
Code:
Text {
    id: debugText
    visible: true
    text: "device:" + 
        sysInfo.machineHostName + "/" +
        sysInfo.prettyProductName + " BundleID:" +
        sysInfo.applicationVersion + "  launchtime:" + new Date()
    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
    font.pointSize: 8
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.leftMargin: 100
    anchors.rightMargin: 200
    color: "#ADD8E6"
}


Does it happen on all macs? Have you tried another version of Qt? Does setting the environment variable QT_OPENGL to "software" have any impact?

Try changing the renderType property.

In your picture, even the text on your titlebar is messed up. Is that a system titlebar, or is the titlebar part of your app as well? To me it looks like a system problem, not a Qt one.
